# Converting a dictionary (passed from C#) to a string in F#

Tags: f#

Edit:
it is solved. The answer is:

```
|> Seq.sortBy (fun (KeyValue(k,v)) -> k)
|> Seq.map (fun (KeyValue(k,v)) -> (sprintf "%s:%s" k v))
|> String.concat ","
```

---

Original question:

I'm trying to do the F# version of this:

```
var postData = "{"
   + string.Join(
       ",",
       sortedParameters.Select(item => $"\"{item.Key}\":\"{item.Value}\"").ToList())
   + "}";
```

I have the following dictionary, coming from C#:

```
{
    { "a", "1" },
    { "c", "3" },
    { "b", "2" },
}
```

I would like to sort it, then output all the values in a string like this:

```
"a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"3"
```

so, I am starting like this:

```
let Test (values : Dictionary<string, string>) : string =
    |> Seq.sortBy (fun (KeyValue(k,v)) -> k)
    |> Seq.iter (fun (KeyValue(k,v)) -> (sprintf "%s:%s" k v))
```

but the last part doesn't compile:

```
Compilation error (line 13, col 50): Type mismatch. Expecting a string -> string -> unit but given a string -> string -> string The type 'unit' does not match the type 'string'
Compilation error (line 13, col 60): This expression was expected to have type string but here has type int
```

I do not understand the error message. My assumption is that this would return me a list of strings like:

```
{
    "a:1", "b:2", "c:3"
}
```

that I would have to join in a string, in the next step

obviously, it's not done like that :)

what did I miss?

Comment: You want `Seq.map`, not `Seq.iter`. The former maps, the latter iterates, ie. it just runs the function on each element, expecting some side-effect.

Comment: ok, got it now:    |> Seq.sortBy (fun (KeyValue(k,v)) -> k)
    |> Seq.map (fun (KeyValue(k,v)) -> (sprintf "%s:%s" k v))
    |> String.concat ","

Comment: the c# -> f# thinking change will still take some time :)

Answer (score 0):

```ml
let showDict (x : Dictionary<string, string>) : string = 
  x
  |> Seq.sortBy (fun (KeyValue (k, v)) -> k)
  |> Seq.map (fun (KeyValue (k, v)) -> $"%s{k}:%s{v}"))
  |> String.concat ", "
```